# Font-size having no effect in UIWebView

Tags: html, objective-c, uiwebview

I have the following code that I am using to place text in a UIWebView however the font does not ever change size.

```
    NSString *htmltext = @"<html><body><font-size=""8""><font face = ""helvetica""><p align = ""justify"">Text.<body><p></body></html>";

    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlheading baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:htmltext]];
```

I have also tried:

```
*htmltext = @"<html><body><font-size:8> ...
*htmltext = @"<html><body><font point-size = ""8""> ...
*htmltext = @"<html><body><font point-size:8> ...
```

What should it be?

Comment: I believe <font-size:8> should be <font size=\"8\">

Comment: Thanks - I tried this but no joy.

Comment: How about doing inline CSS then - <p style=\"font-size:8px;\">...</p>, or adding CSS within a head tag.

Comment: As @Nick said, try it with CSS and it should work. If it didn't just give a buzz here and I will show you the code I used once to do this. (I'm mobile now!)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML looks kind of strange in that the `"` charater generally needs to be escaped in an `NSString` literal. In other words, I have done similar things before and it worked just fine. Try something like `\"` every place where you have a quote character in the HTML.

After taking a closer look at your code and HTML, you appear to have several other issues. Your call to `webView loadHTML...` passess the HTML text as the second parameter, which should be `nil`, instead of the first and your HTML itself looks pretty mangled with mismatched tags etc.

When doing this kind of thing, it is always advisable to test your HTML separately and add it to your code only after you are sure it displays properly. For instance, HTML5, the latest version of the standard, ignores the font tag, which means you should be using CSS.

That said, the following worked just fine for me.

```
NSString *htmltext = @"<html><body><p style=\"font-family:helvetica;font-size:12;text-align:justify\">Text.</p></body></html>";
```